# How to get text in table of contents aligned after numbers?

Tags: microsoft-word, text-editing, text-formatting, table-of-contents, alignment

Is it possible to get a table of contents in Microsoft Word with an alignment like this picture? If so, how?

[image]

(In the picture the alignment is not perfect because I did it by hand, inserting spaces and dots.)

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the paragraph styles that are involved (TOC 1, TOC 2, TOC3, etc.), adjusting the paragraph settings for so that they all have the same left indent (e.g., 0), and left and right tabs at the same locations (with a dot leader applied to the right tab; this should already be set for you, though). When you insert a TOC in one of the predefined TOC styles, you should get the result shown in your screen capture.

Answer (score 0):

With your entire list selected, grab the Hanging Indent slider on the ruler at the top of the page and slowly drag it a couple of steps to the right (assuming you are a left to right language user) until you get the alignment you prefer.

Note, the Hanging Indent slider is the indicator that is roughly like an upward pointing arrow. From top to bottom you have:
The 'First Line Indent', which is a down arrow above the ruler
Then the Hanging Indent slider, which is an up arrow below the ruler which is also usually attached to the Left Indent slider.

Please note, it sometimes seems to be a bit tricky to grab the slider the right way.

[image: Hanging Indent slider in Word]